# How to get Network Speed in AppRTC

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtc

I am developing iOS video application based on apprtc libraries, I need would like to show "**poor network connection**" to the user.

Can anyone help me on how to determine the slow network connection while having video conversation.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the proper tag like Objective c or swift. So that anyone can help you out... Also mention at which stage you are. i am having done what you tried to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi ashok, i am using objective-c to develop video calling functionality, if the network is very low i would like to show the user  "poor network connection" as banner. so i am not able to find any solution for this.

Comment: please update your question with this details